# How to allow users to change their own passwords in Django?

Tags: python, django

Can any one point me to code where users can change their own passwords in Django?

Comment: -1 for 'plzsendmetehcodes'. BTW, you should accept correct answer on your questions.

Comment: Yeah, I used to use Google a lot, and still do. But SO is easier and faster, and you can engage in discussions and hear alternative answers. As long as there are folks like Svetlozer Angelov and others, who are willing to invest their time (and earn points) for answering simple questions, well, that's what SO is for.

Comment: Django has such comprehensive and easily accessible documentation, that the ongoing attempts to replicate all documentation ever in SO answers can't possibly add any value.

Comment: @Ben James: such a good point. Actually that is why instead of rewriting the documentation in my answers I just give the barebone information and link to the docs.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

> Django comes with a user
>   authentication system. It handles user
>   accounts, groups, permissions and
>   cookie-based user sessions. This
>   document explains how things work.

[How to change Django passwords](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/)

See the **Changing passwords** section

1. Navigation to your project where `manage.py` file lies
2. `$ python manage.py shell`
3. type below scripts :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(username__exact='john')
u.set_password('new password')
u.save()
```

---

You can also use the simple `manage.py` command:

`manage.py changepassword *username*`

Just enter the new password twice.

from the [*Changing passwords*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords) section in the docs.

---

If you have the `django.contrib.admin` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, you can visit: `example.com/path-to-admin/password_change/` which will have a form to confirm your old password and enter the new password twice.

Comment: I don't think this helps create pages for users to change their own passwords—just an admin to do it.

Answer (score 28):

You can also just use the `django.contrib.auth.views.password_change` view in your URLconf. It uses a default form and template; supplying your own is optional.

Answer (score 8):

[This tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/04/django-tip-9-password-change-form.html) shows how to do it with function based views:

View file:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  # Important!
            messages.success(request, 'Your password was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('change_password')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'accounts/change_password.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Url file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from myproject.accounts import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
]
```

And finally, the template:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Its without need to go to shell enter passwd and reenter passwd

```
 python manage.py changepassword <username> 
  or
/manage.py changepassword <username>
```

Using shell

```
python manage.py shell
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
users=User.objects.filter(email='<user_email>') 
  #you can user username or etc to get users query set
  #you can also use get method to get users
user=users[0]
user.set_password('__enter passwd__')
user.save()
exit()
```

Comment: OP asked how users can change their own paswords, not just admininstrators

Answer (score 3):

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Template:

```
<a href="{% url 'password_change' %}">{% trans "Change password" %}</a>
```

Documented at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views

Answer (score 2):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/), use:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import makepassword
```

The main reason to do this is that Django uses hashed passwords to store in the database.

```
password=make_password(password,hasher='default')
obj=User.objects.filter(empid=emp_id).update(username=username,password=password)
```

I used this technique for the custom user model which is derived from the `AbstractUser` model. I am sorry if I technically misspelled the class and subclass, but the technique worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication is the one way and after that reset the password

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
user = authenticate(username='username',password='passwd')
try:
  if user is not None:
     user.set_password('new password')
  else:
     print('user is not exist')
except:
  print("do something here")
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the url pattern is added as shown in Ciro Santilli's answer, a quick way to allow users to change passwords is to give them "staff access" for the admin functions.  If you don't add them to any groups or give them special permissions, they can still change their password by going to the example.com/admin page.  The staff access lets them go to the page even if it is blank; in the upper right corner they can click "change password" and use the admin funtionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is the command i used, just in case you are having problem in that throw `AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'users.User'`.

```
python manage.py shell -c "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; 
User = get_user_model(); 
u = User.objects.get(username='admin'); 
u.set_password('password123');
u.save()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to @Ciro's answer, but more specific to the original question (without adding all the authentication views):

just add to `urlpatterns` in `urls.py`:

```
url('^change-password/$', auth_views.password_change, {'post_change_redirect': 'next_page'}, name='password_change'),
```

Note that `post_change_redirect` specifies the url to redirect after the password is changed.

Then, just add to your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'password_change' %}">Change Password</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

view.py

```
views.py

  def changepassword(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
        user_id = request.POST['user_id']
        oldpassword = request.POST['oldpassword']
        newpassword = request.POST['newpassword']
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        if **user.check_password**(oldpassword):
          **user.set_password(newpassword)**
          user.save()
          return redirect("app:login-user")
        else:
         messages.success(request,"Pervious Password Not Match")
         return redirect("app:changepassword")
     else:
       return render(request,'app/changepassword.html')
```

url.py

```
path('changepassword',views.changepassword,name='changepassword'),
```