# authenticate of django doesnt work

Tags: django, authentication, passwords

I am working on a password reset for django, but whatever I try the reset doesn't work. So i checked what my form handled on data which i knew had to be true. It still didn't work. So alst i tried to authenticate in the django shell. and this is what happened.

shell:

```
In [11]: user = User.objects.first()
In [12]: password = "bier"
In [13]: user.set_password(password)
In [14]: i = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
In [15]: i
i returns None
```

Someone any clue about what is causing this?

Comment: Have you tried to save the user? User.save() ?

Comment: Post that as an answer @Lara

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873806/changing-password-in-django

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should save your user object,

```
user.save()
```

According to the docs, user object is not saved:

"Sets the user’s password to the given raw string, taking care of the password hashing. Doesn’t save the User object."

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(username='john')
u.set_password('new password')
u.save()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users